# How to trace the source of dynamically set css?

Tags: css, debugging

This is a question about bug tracing. I have a WP site in which I am experiencing a plugin conflict. One of the plugins is applying "display;none" to some elements in a slider. What I am wondering is whether there is a good method for knowing what code is setting that css?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it usually with firefox + firebug, firefox' own inspect element, chromes developer tools etc, when you inspect an element it tells you which .css file is being used.

Alternatively, if you turn off all your plugins and enable them one by one you can tell where the conflict is and check that plugins folder. If you have access to the plugins folder on your server you can see if there is a .css file in there - or open the main .php file as some plugin devs put their css straight into there.

But using a developer tool should give you an idea as to where the css is being generated. Even if it is dynamic, combining developer tools with simple plugin troubleshooting will narrow the information down enough to give you the jist of where it is.